# How to convert String to Set<Object>?

Tags: java

I have the following DTOs:

```
public class ConsumerDTO {
    private String amount;
    //...some other fields
}

public class ReceiverDTO {
    private Set<PriceInfoDto> prices;
//...some other fields
}

public class PriceInfoDto {
    private String amount;
    //...some other fields
}
```

I want to convert ConsumerDTO to ReceiverDTO, p.s. map my data between differently structured objects. ConsumerDTO is my source class. ReceiverDTO is my target class. I tried this:

```
TypeMap<ConsumerDTO , ReceiverDTO> propertyMapper = this.mapper.createTypeMap(ConsumerDTO .class, ReceiverDTO.class);
    propertyMapper.addMapping(ConsumerDTO ::getAmount, ReceiverDTO::getAmount);
```

But having trouble with getting amount from set in my target class. Is there a way to solve this? I also read some articles, but they show examples with simple types.

Comment: Please show your attempt at solving this.  And you have yet to take the [tour].  I also recommend you check out [ask].

Comment: @WJS Thanks, but I showed what I tried and I stucked in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve the *target object* of **`ReceiverDTO`** from your *source object* **`ConsumerDTO`** as below:

***Approach Here:***

Here, I have added few more sample fields in the source as well as target class to show how to map other fields while creating a target object of type `ReceiverDTO` using `getTargetTypeObject` method.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Source class objects
        ConsumerDTO sourceObj = new ConsumerDTO();
        sourceObj.setAmount("100");
        //sample for Other fields in source object
        sourceObj.setName("test");
        sourceObj.setId(1000);
        sourceObj.setFlag(true);
        //sample for Other fields in source object
        ReceiverDTO targetType = getTargetTypeObject(sourceObj);
        System.out.println(targetType);
    }

    private static ReceiverDTO getTargetTypeObject(ConsumerDTO x) {
        //Intermediate object creations
        PriceInfoDto dto = new PriceInfoDto();
        dto.setAmount(x.getAmount());
        //Set other fields like this
        dto.setName(x.getName());
        dto.setId(x.getId());
        dto.setFlag(x.isFlag());
        //Set other fields like this
        Set<PriceInfoDto> set = new HashSet<>();
        set.add(dto);
        //Target object
        ReceiverDTO receiverDTO = new ReceiverDTO();
        receiverDTO.setPrices(set);
        return receiverDTO;
    }
}

class ConsumerDTO {
    private String amount;
    private String name;
    private int id;
    private boolean flag;
    //getters and setters
    //toString
}

class ReceiverDTO {
    private Set<PriceInfoDto> prices;
    //getters and setters
    //toString
}

class PriceInfoDto {
    private String amount;
    private String name;
    private int id;
    private boolean flag;
    //getters and setters
    //toString
}
```

**Output:**

```
ReceiverDTO{prices=[PriceInfoDto{amount='100', name='test', id=1000, flag=true}]}
```

Comment: What if I dont have a list of ConsumerDTO? Is this approach also possible for only ConsumerDTO?

Comment: @Alex Yes you can go with **Approach 2** in which you can use `getTargetTypeObject` directly by passing your source `ConsumerDTO` object and you will get `ReceiverDTO` target type object in return.

Comment: But what if I have not only this field in my source class, but several different fields I need to map with other different field types in my targer class, should I write getTargetTypeObject method for all of them? And then there is a question, how I gonna map all of them? I think calling each method is not possible while mapping.

Comment: @Alex I have updated the code showing how to map other fields while creating the target object , you need to set in `PriceInfoDto dto` object from `ConsumerDTO x` in `getTargetTypeObject` method as shown in the code above. And you can use the same method just you need to update this method with other fields mapping.